# Update Item Cart change to delete and add

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want change update item in woocomerce. I use plugin (sumo measures) to calculate metadata (size, pack) and when I try to update quantity of cart product metadata dont change.

My idea to solution problem is remove item from cart and add.

My code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated', 'on_action_cart_updated', 20, 1 );
function on_action_cart_updated( $cart_updated ){
    
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_updated ){
             $product_id = $cart_updated['product_id'];
         WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $cart_updated['quantity'] );
    }

    
}
```

But code dont work.

Comment: Would you like to keep a single product in the cart and update its quantity?

Answer (score 0):

I find using this action hook : **woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated**

Using this you can get the cart data: **$cart = WC()->cart->cart_contents;**

You can get the cart itemmeta and quantity and then update the Sumo measures cart item data.

Because to remove and re-add the product with updated quantity will be the length process and also there will be much other factors need to take care.

Please let me know if you find any issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea how to update the sumo data. The plugin doesn't have any page with information. For this reason, I wanted to do it this way